# I cannot play a DVD in Fedora 18 despite a ton of research and terminal time.

Tags: video, dvd, vlc-media-player, codec, gstreamer

Help! I have tried everything I can think of. I've done a ton of research and installed a lot of stuff via terminal and I cannot figure out how to get a DVD to play in Fedora 18.

I've installed Fedora utils, gstreamer, VLC, Flash plugins, etc. Still, when I pop the DVD in... nothing happens. When I go into both Videos and VLC, the DVD is not recognized and won't play.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You missed [*one* little package...](http://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#How_can_I_install_libdvdcss.3F)

> ### How can I install libdvdcss?
>
> In some European countries it is illegal to distribute it in binary form. Therefore RPM Fusion has chosen not to carry libdvdcss in its repositories.
>
> [Livna](http://rpm.livna.org/) and [Freshrpms](http://freshrpms.net/) will provide libdvdcss for the foreseeable future.